# save local data fulfillment dialogflow nodejs

Tags: google-cloud-functions, dialogflow-es, telegram-bot, dialogflow-es-fulfillment

when I use dialogflow + google assistant, I usually save a temporary data with `conv.data` and save to user storage with `conv.user.storage` in webhook cloud function javascript

but, when I use dialogflow + telegram, I didn't find that.
so I want to save a score in quiz, so in 10 question, the system able to store like a temporary storage to save the score and calculate after the quiz is finish

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both `conv.data` and `conv.user.storage` are Actions on Google concepts, so are only available with that integration.

The rough equivalent of `conv.data` would be to have a [Context](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/es/docs/contexts-overview) with a long [lifespan](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/es/docs/contexts-input-output#lifespan). Your webhook would save the data you're interested in preserving for the session in this context and then retrieve it in a later webhook call.

This is only maintained for a session, however. Any longer-term storage would require you to have a unique identifier for the user which you can use as a key into a database or data store you maintain.